# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL when using SQLite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

The error I get is:

> Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid.

Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  user: test-app
  encoding: unicode
```

And my Gemfile:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development

group :production do
  # For Heroku
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

This *identical* setup works fine with another app, but for some reason refuses to here. Why is it even looking for PostgreSQL in development?

Comment: When running `rails c` or sending any web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

I am using the gem `dotenv` to load my Heroku ENV vars from the `.env` file into Rails, one of which is a Heroku Postgres URL in the variable `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` that was messing with Rails in development.

I removed it and Rails started working properly again.

Answer (score 0):

In the database.yml file, the adapter in production should be 'postgresql' not 'pg'.

Comment: Changed it, didn't make a difference. It shouldn't even be looking at the production database details in development.

Comment: Did you `bundle install` after editing your Gemfile?